# Get the value of the textfield of CKEditor's image dialog window

Tags: javascript, dialog, ckeditor

My requirement is that, I need to display the values entered by the user in the image properties of the dialog box in the CKEditor. How to display that? For example:- if there is a field description and if the user has entered anything in that field, then along with image, that description should also be displayed in the CKEditor. How to do that?

```
 dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e) {
                  var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;
                  //var description = $("#imageDescription").getValue();

                  var description="this is the description"; 
                  var imgHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<table><tr><td><img src=" + imageSrcUrl + " alt='' /><td></tr><tr><td>"+description+"</td></tr></table>"); 
                   editor.insertElement(imgHtml);
       }
```

Please tell me how to get the value of the textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre looking for [`getValue`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-getValue) method. Also see an official [guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1) (+ [part 2](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2)) to dialog development.